# Prove that $D$ is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces, field-theory, group-homomorphism

Here is the question I want to answer:

Let $F$ be a field and $D$ an integral domain which is a finite dimensional vector space over $F.$ Prove that $D$ is also a field.

**Here are my thoughts:**

Since $F$ is a field, then every nonzero element in $F$ has a multiplicative inverse. Since $D$ is an integral domain, then it has no zero divisors i.e., if $ab = 0$ then either $a=0$ of $b =0$ for every $a,b \in D.$ **I do not really understand why we need the assumption that $D$ is a finite dimensional vector space (in case there is a proof simpler than the one given in the question mentioned below).** Do I have to define a map as given in the second answer here [Let $R$ be an integral ring and let $F$ be a field contained in $R$. $R$ is a vector space over $F$. Show that $R$ is a field.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1812242/let-r-be-an-integral-ring-and-let-f-be-a-field-contained-in-r-r-is-a-ve)  or is there a very simple way of proving this question?

Comment: $D$ being finite dimensional implies it is integral over $F$. Now use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450020/integral-extensions-of-rings-when-one-of-the-rings-is-a-field.

Comment: There is indeed a very simple solution. Saying that $D$ is a field is equivalent to saying that all the $F$-linear maps $x\mapsto ax$ for $a\in D$ are bijections. Can you use the two hypotheses to prove that?

Comment: This is probably one of the most duplicated questions in the ring-theory tag.

Comment: @CaptainLama so there is no way to solve it without defining this linear map?

Comment: @Brain Of course there are other ways. You can just note that if $\{b_1,\ldots, b_n\}$ is a basis then so is $\{ab_1,\ldots, ab_n\}$, and therefore there is a linear combination $\sum \lambda_iab_i=1$, whence you have an inverse for $a$, namely $\sum \lambda_ib_i$.  This all assumes $a$ is nonzero, naturally.  This used to be at one of the duplicates but I think possibly the associated post was deleted.

Comment: I want the easiest solution ..... is this only the solution? @rschwieb

Comment: @Brain Uh... I just told you a second solution so obviously there's no "only" solution. Both solutions are pretty dead simple.  I'm not sure what more you're asking for at this point.

Comment: No I meant ..... is your second solution is a whole solution or there are more details I should fill in in it?@rschwieb